# Compiling library for java 1.4 using maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, xstream

I need very basic lib that allows create `json` string from class object. I would like to compile `xstream` library for `java 1.4` .  For this purpose I'm planning to use `Eclipse Mars IDE` . I have extracted xstream to `C:\j\xstream` :

```
[.]                     README.txt              [xstream-distribution]
[..]                    settings-template.xml   [xstream-hibernate]
BUILD.txt               svn-autoprops.config
LICENSE.txt             [xstream]
pom.xml                 [xstream-benchmark]
```

in Build.txt found message:

```
copy settings-template.xml to ~/.m2/settings.xml adding your Codehaus DAV username and passwords.
```

Regarding settings - no problem. But where I can get Codehaus username and pass?

I have no much experience with maven. What steps I should perform to create maven project to compile library. I do:

```
File->New->Other->MavenProject
```

And there I'm sucked in. What to choose :

```
Create simple project
Use default Workspace location
Add projects to working set
```

What other steps I need to perform?

Comment: It  sounds like you are following the instructions for doing maintenance development on xstream. Is that really what you want to do? xstream is available on maven central, so you only need to add it as a dependency of the code you want to write.

Comment: if it is possible on maven central how I can download it from there for java 1.4. I need to put it to project that is not using maven. On xstream webpage I can download compiled for java 8.

Comment: xstream is written using java 8, so it is extremely unlikely you would be able to compile or use it using java 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

For your immediate problem, you need to do:

`File->Import->Maven->Existing Maven Project`, `Browse` to where you have downloaded xstream, `Finish`.

But as explained in comments, I suspect that won't get you very far. Java 1.4 came out in 2002, predating the time JSON was widely used. The current version of xstream uses at least generics and annotations.

Maybe one of the archived libraries at http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/xstream/xstream/ will work? Or can you relax the constraint on java 1.4?

Or simply don't use a library and print out the JSON by hand.